# Private member of class accessed in main method

Tags: java, access-modifiers

let's assume we have the following code:

```
 public class TestScope {
      private int a = 1;
         public static void main(String[] args) {
           TestScope ts = new TestScope();
           ts.a = 6;
           System.out.println(ts.a);
        }
    }
```

Why at line: `ts.a = 6;` I can get access to private variable `a`?
I thought that private memebers cannot be accessed outside. I don't underestend this example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I access a private variable from main method ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707504/why-can-i-access-a-private-variable-from-main-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `a` and `main(String[])` are both part of the definition of the class `TestScope`

Private means that a variable or method can only be accessed inside **the class definition**. The fact that a is an instance variable doesn't mean it can't be accessed by a static public method in the same class.

If the `public static void main(String[])` was inside a different class, then it would not be able to access `ts`'s `a`, because `a` is hidden from other classes.

Answer (score 6):

Static methods are still considered part of the class they're declared in, and thus have access to private methods/fields.

If you had the main method (or any other static or instance method) in another class, you would indeed not be able to access a.

Comment: or more specificly, static methods *defined inside a class* are still considered part of *that class*.

Answer (score 2):

A static method is considered 'part' of the class it's in and so has private-scope access to instances of it. This same question was tackled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707504/why-can-i-access-a-private-variable-from-main-method) a couple days ago.