# Confused with why private variable can be accessed?

Tags: java

I recently see a question that what is the execution result of this code below.

```
public class Sandys {
    private int court;
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        Sandys s = new Sandys(99);
        System.out.println(s.court);
    }
    Sandys(int ballcount){
        court = ballcount;
    }
}
```

I think it can't be executed because in `main` i try to access a private variable.

However, this code can be perfectly executed, and the result is `99`. So I am confused, why the private variable can be accessed in this code? Though the `main` is in `Sandys` class, however i create a new `Sandys`. Can I still access the private variable of the new `Sandys` object in `main`?

Comment: Answer is here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707504/why-can-i-access-a-private-variable-from-main-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access private members from inside the same class, even in static methods.

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is a special method because it is used as a starting point for java application. **However, it is still a normal static method and it follows all access restrictions of static methods**. Is this `main()` a class method? Yes, it is. Hence, it can access private members of the same class.

Consider this: if there was no access to private fields factory methods would have to be written differently.

```
class A {
  private int a=0;
  private int b=0;

  private A() {}

  //getters

  public static A getNewInstance(int a, int b) {
    A a = new A();
    a.a = a;
    a.b = b;
    return A;
  }
```

It does make sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access ALL **private**, protected, public and not modifier variables inside class, but you can not access private variable from **another** class.

P.S. It is truth also for C#, C++ and many other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

A class is defined to some particular job and in that way it may use some variables that  it don't want others to access it("others" means outsider classes) and some you want other classes to access it.It all depends on your requirement.

**"Private instance variables are defined to be used in only with in the class"**.and since in your code you are trying                to access the private instance variable inside the class itself then it is perfectly legal.

Note: A static method cannot access the instance variables if u want specify the instance i mean create the instance(object) inside of the static method and access it through the created reference.