# Why won't my "private" keyword on var " first" work?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working the CS61b these days. And I got stuck at the lecture of Access control. My "private" keyword on variable first and class IntNode can't work properly.

Searched on Google but found nothing.

```java
public class SLList {
    private IntNode first;

    /**
     * If the nested class never uses any instance variables or methods of the outer
     * class, declare it static.
     */
    private static class IntNode {
        public IntNode next;
        public int item;

        public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
            next = n;
            item = i;
        }

    }

    public SLList(int x) {
        first = new IntNode(x, null);
    }



    public void addFirst(int x) {
        first = new IntNode(x, first);
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first.item;
    }
/** ----------------SIZE---------------------- */
    private int size(IntNode L) {
        if (L.next == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 1 + size(L.next);
    }

    public int size() {
        return size(first);
    }
/**-------------------SIZE------------------- */


/**---------------add LAST ------------------*/
/** how to solve null pointer expectation? */
    public void addLast(int x) {
        IntNode p=first;
        while(p.next!=null){
            p=p.next;
        }
        p.next=new IntNode(x, null);
    }
/**---------------add LAST ------------------*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SLList L = new SLList(5);
        L.addFirst(10);
        L.addFirst(15);
        System.out.println(L.getFirst());
        System.out.println(L.size());
        L.addLast(20);
        L.first.next.next = L.first.next;  /** <----- I can still get√ access to first. */

    }
}
```

I expected to has error: first has private class in SLList,
but I got nothing wrong.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to access a private field in the same class? Do you expect a private field not to be used by it's class? If it is not accessible by it's own class, who should be able to use it then?

Comment: If you moved the `main` method to another class (as it would be in any real-life application), you would indeed get the expected error.

Comment: This thread may help a bit more to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707504/why-can-i-access-a-private-variable-from-main-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See The [Java Language Specification §6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - If the member or constructor is declared public, then access is permitted.
> - All members of interfaces lacking access modifiers are implicitly public.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
>   - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.
>   - Access is correct as described in [§6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2).
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared with package access, then access is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.
>
>   A class member or constructor declared without an access modifier implicitly has package access.
> - Otherwise, the member or constructor is **declared private**, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the **body of the top level type ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6))** that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

(Emphasis mine)

As your access to `first` is within the same top level type, you can access it without any problems, errors or anything else.